# Нахождение данных по дате через DATEDIFF и DATEPART в SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

```
Select код_читателя,
        фамилия,
        имя,
        отчество,
        дата_рождения,
        паспортные_данные,
        адрес,
        контактный_телефон
from dbo.Читатели_2
WHERE 
datediff(year, Читатели_2.дата_рождения, getdate()) >= 18 and
DATEPART(month, Читатели_2.дата_рождения) <= DATEPART(month, getdate()) and
datediff(day, Читатели_2.дата_рождения, getdate()) <= DATEPART(day, getdate())
```

Нужно вывести данные по тем, кому уже есть 18 лет, начиная от системной даты. Никак не могу сделать корректный подсчёт по дню. То есть, если человек родился 2001.06.20, то ему всё ещё нет 18.

Comment: а просто из даты отнять 18 лет и сравнить нельзя?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Читатели_2
WHERE 
Читатели_2.дата_рождения <= dateadd(year, -18, getdate())
```

Comment: Лучше, когда поле таблицы в условии не находиться внутри функции, т.е. `дата_рождения < dateadd(year, -18, getdate())`. Тогда выражение вычисляется только один раз, а не для каждой строки

Comment: *кому уже есть 18 лет* - так что условие сравнения должно быть нестрогим, т.е. `<=`.